# How do I convert a single page PDF document to a preview image using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pdf

As my question says ..
I want to show my pdf file as a preview image(size of a thumb nail) when clicked on, using angularjs.

So far i have only found ways on how to view a pdf file on a webpage or how to preview image before uploading.

Any idea on which directives i can use or a path that i should follow.

I am lost beyond hope.

Any help no matter how small, is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can achieve this only by using some backend workaround.
You must prepeare preview image for PDF.

You can use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/) to get first page of PDF. Then you can convert it to image using imagemagic. Here is some [workaround](https://gist.github.com/yura/670974). I hove it will help you.

Comment: Hey .. the problem is that i have a lot of pdf files that show up through ng-repeat, and an option where i can upload new pdf's too .. do i need to make a preview image for each pdf ?

Comment: Lets say you have upload form, when you upload file after save you need to create preview for uploaded file, this process not so fast, but there are no alternatives. You can show some image placeholder untill preview not created. You must create preview only once and then show it if exists.

Comment: Ok Александр Муляр. Thanks a lot for the information. i will keep searching for other means.